# Gather list of structs in MPI for Python?

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I am currently trying to communicate lists of struct objects but I run into an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Primary_secondary_co-sim.py", line 509, in <module>
    sm_clear_all(params, curr_pri_timestep, soln)
    File "/home/gridsan/jvineet9/vvc_sims/code/sm_clear_all.py", line 
    162, in sm_clear_all
    node_num = soln_node['node_num']
    TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
    Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
    a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been 
    aborted.
    ----------------------------------------------------------------- 

    mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero 
    status, thus causing
    the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

    Process name: [[56840,1],1]
    Exit code:    1
```

Here is my code:

```py
from mpi4py import MPI
import os

data = [4,5]
num_SMOs = 5
solns_list = []

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

name = MPI.Get_processor_name()
pid = os.getpid()

idx = range(num_SMOs)
myidx = idx[rank:len(idx):size] 

for node in myidx:

    soln_node = structtype()

    # Add some data fields to struct
    soln_node.node_num = node
    soln_node.XX = data

    solns_list.append(soln_node)

# All nodes send their solns to rank 0

solns_nodes_all = comm.gather(solns_list, root=0)

if rank == 0:

    for soln_node in solns_nodes_all: 

        node_num = soln_node.node_num
        data = soln_node.XX
```

And here's definition for the struct python object:

```py
class structtype:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

I get the error at the line "for soln_node in solns_nodes_all:" when I loop through all the nodes. I expected solns_nodes_all to be a list of structs as constructed but instead it looks like it's become a list of lists after the MPI gather step?

Comment: Show some code. mpi4py has two types of routines: `Gather` works on numpy arrays but `gather` works on python objects. Sounds like you might need the latter.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just added some example code. Hopefully this makes the problem clearer?

Comment: For good measure  include the exact error message with trackback?

Comment: Added the error message above - "smo_sol" is being treated as a list even though I created it as a struct. Not sure why?

Comment: `smo_sol` is not used in the snippet you shared.

Comment: Sorry just corrected that

Comment: Your error and code don't match, you're creating too many assumptions and post partial information based on those assumptions. Please create an actually reproducible minimal example, remove all your guesses from the question and limit it to just the code, and the observed error. You are at least missing some imports in the code you posted.

Comment: Even after fixing the imports `num_SMOs` is undefined for example

Answer (score 0):

`mpi4py`s `gather` operation fetches individual values from nodes, and puts those return values into a list. You return lists, so they are put into a **list of lists**. If you intended to return multiple values but want a flat list to iterate over, you can chain your iterables together:

```py
import itertools

for soln_node in itertools.chain.from_iterable(solns_nodes_all):
    node_num = soln_node.node_num
    data = soln_node.XX
```

You could have found this out by printing the value of `solns_nodes_all`:

```
[
  [<__main__.structtype object at 0x7ff148535c70>, <__main__.structtype object at 0x7ff148535700>],
  [<__main__.structtype object at 0x7ff148535ee0>, <__main__.structtype object at 0x7ff148535dc0>],
  [<__main__.structtype object at 0x7ff148535f40>]
]
```

The general pattern of `gather` goes like this:

```
Node 1 returns A
Node 2 returns B
Node 3 returns C
Gathered into [A, B, C]
```

So if you say `A=[struct(), struct()]`, ... then what is gathered is `[[struct(), struct()], ...]`